# Archive (Compress) giant folder in Linux using command line without termination

Tags: linux, tar, signals

Well, I'm just trying to compress a whole directory (infact giant!) under Linux using a terminal. The entire folder size is about 7 GB. I've used below command to create the archive.

```
tar -zcvf myArchieve.tar.gz myFolder
```

It's working but in middle it stops by displaying `Terminated` message in the terminal. I could see the archive file created but there were missing file(s)/sub folder(s). in the compressed file. I want to create the entire folder (7 GB) Archive without any 'Terminated' message timeout. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How much memory you have?

Comment: Perhaps first try to create the archive without compressing it? This may help in troubleshooting where the issue lies.

Comment: Do you have permissions to access these files? Are these real files or device files or pipes or something else? I compress directories of files larger than this and it works fine.

Comment: @slm I've permissions & these are normal files hosted in GoDaddy server & I'm doing the operation through SSH.

Comment: @JensonMJohn - fair enough, just making sure. Is there any info about the names of these files? Can you tar just them?

Comment: @slm Sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: @JensonMJohn - when the terminated message shows up, I'm assuming it's for the same files, if so is there anything special about these files?

Comment: @slm No, they're just normal files itself. I just want to know whether any timeout period for any Linux command operation or will it continue to execute until it's completion?

Comment: @JensonMJohn - in my experience it will often times continue over these problematic files, and the resulting archive will just be missing these files.

Comment: What is the status code from the `tar` command (run `echo $?` immediately after)? Is this some antique (20th century) system which doesn't support files larger than 4GB? Does anything appear in the kernel logs?